# Automate Azure SQL database creation and add a database user

Tags: sql, database, azure, pipeline

I'm configuring a pipeline to deploy a test environment for an app, along with app services and storage there is a SQL database. I have already automated the creation of all of them in azure and is working.

After the test is finished, the environment is destroyed to save resources until a new test is required.

Now I need to add a SQL user to the test database while deploying, it's on the same server, to simplify the login already exists, so I want to assign the same to the new database.

Something like this.

- Server1   already has user1 as login (was manually created)
- Database1 already has user1 as user (was manually assigned)

Desired:

- Add User1 as user of database2

There is a way to automate this while building the test environment?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go for IF NOT EXISTS and create login and user accordingly.

```sql
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT name 
                FROM [sys].[server_principals]
                WHERE name = N'test')
 BEGIN
    CREATE LOGIN test WITH password = 'TestPassword'
 END

 IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT name 
                FROM [sys].[database_principals]
                WHERE name = N'test')
 BEGIN
    CREATE USER test for login test;
 END
```

Comment: Hi @Venkataraman R thanks for your sugestion, it's working now, but instead of server_principals am using sys.sql_logins.